# Show that two planes are not the same plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The plane equations are:

V1 = 2x+3y+z=6

V2 = 4x+6y+2z=9

Now I can see that V2 is not a multiple of V1 due to 9 not being divisible by 2 unlike the other coefficients. But I don't believe it is as simple as that since the question weighs quite a bit. I am also not sure how to represent 2 plane equations being the same.

I tried moving the constant over to the left of each equation and then equating the two to get 2x+3y+z+3=0.

But this is clearly not a sufficient show of how they aren't the same.
Any advice or theory is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's quite easy to see that the $V_2$ is just 3 units lower than $V_1$

Comment: yes I also see the difference. But for a 5 mark question, I doubt that would be an appropriate response.

Comment: On a second zoomed in inspection of the poorly scanned exam question. Its possible that the mark allocation might be a 3 which is more likely.

Comment: $(3,0,0)$ belongs to $V_1$, but not to $V_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing the second equation by $2$ we get
$$2x+3y+z=\frac{9}{2}\neq 6$$

Comment: In particular this shows that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to one equation it does not solve the other, hence the planes cannot even intersect.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. It makes sense.

Comment: This can also be a question for my students, thank you too